# Deviation location on drawline according to mouseClicked Point

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, java-2d, mouselistener

Having a `JPanel` on a JFrame  , the `JPanel` is as the follow   -

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener,
        MouseMotionListener {
    ...
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg) {
            ...
        Point p = arg.getPoint();
            // save this point  ... 
            ...
            repaint();

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        ...
        // point1 & point2 are the last two clicked point ..
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int x1 = point1.x;
        int y1 = point1.y;

        int x2 = point2.x;
        int y2 = point2.y;
        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }

}
```

My problem is that the `drawline` paint the line with a slightly deviation from the real clicked point location on the originator component   .

I attach some screenshots which clear it some more  -

The upper line edges are the 2 points I clicked on them  , the lower line is the line received from the `drawline` , and as you can see these 2 line doesn't overlap .

click 1  -

[image]

click 2 -

[image]

output line -

[image]

Any helpful solution ?

Comment: The clicked points must have been defined w.r.t the `JFrame` not the `JPanel`, as you can see that the vertical distance between the two parallel lines is equal to the width of the titlebar.

Comment: Great ! 
 I just set the `addMouseListener` according to the `JPanel` and it fixed !